# Query for the top 20 item wise record of every customer

Tags: sql

I have a table sales invoice, there are itemno, custno, and quantity, date. i want top 3 record of every customer with item details in Descending Order (top sales sum(quantity)).
means let say

```
c1 i1 sum(quantity)
c1 i2 sum(quantity)
c1 i3 sum(quantity)
c2 i2 sum(quantity)
c2 i5 sum(quantity)
c2 i3 sum(quantity)
```

and so on.let me know if anymore clarification required

Comment: Can you give an example of concrete input and matching concrete output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server, using common table expressions CTE

```
;WITH SumQty AS -- The data format we wish to display
(
    SELECT CustNo, ItemNo, SUM(Quantity) AS SumQty 
    FROM SalesInvoice
    GROUP BY CustNo, ItemNo
),
Seq AS -- The grouping of customer order by qty of items in descending order
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY CustNo ORDER BY SumQty DESC) AS Seq, 
        * 
    FROM SumQty 
)
SELECT 
    CustNo,
    ItemNo,
    SumQty 
FROM Seq
WHERE Seq <= 3 -- Interested on top 3 for each customer only
```

Comment: can u explain query according to my field name, i want custno, itemno and    quantity only. every customer's top 3 itemno's sales qty (sum of quanity) should be display on output. (on given example c1 and c2 are customer and i1, i2,i3 and so on items are in the table i want only top 3 record of sum qty in descending order.

Comment: Thanks Eric when i try following query getting an error (Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 18
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.)    ;WITH SumQty AS
(
    SELECT 
 No_,[Bill-to Customer No_], Sum([Quantity (Base)]) AS SumQty 
    FROM [Bodycare Creations$Sales Invoice Line]
    GROUP BY No_,[Bill-to Customer No_]
),
Seq AS
(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Bill-to Customer No_] ORDER BY SumQty DESC) AS Seq, 
        * 
    FROM SumQty 
)
SELECT 
No_,
[Bill-to Customer No_], 
FROM Seq
WHERE Seq <= 3

Comment: Sorry Eric. it was my fault. query executed successfully. and thank you so very much for your great help.

Answer (score 0):

You may try something like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT s.custid, s.itemno, sum(s.quantity) as quantity_new
    FROM Salesinvoice AS s 
    GROUP BY s.custid, s.itemno)
GROUP BY custid, itemno
HAVING COUNT(custid) <= 3 
ORDER BY quantity_new DESC;
```